# Hide error message in vb6

Tags: vb6

Is theres a way to hide a vb6 error? I have a program that prompt an error but everything goes fine. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.
**UPD** the code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'passing the values to program2 
strCommand = """" & App.Path & "\Prog2.exe """ & strArgs(0) & ";" & Trim$(.cFileName) & ";" & strArgs(1) WshShell.Run strCommand
```

Comment: is that all? only two lines of code? and where is the wrapping code (on error resume next, etc)? can you show the full code or it is a big secret?:)

Comment: tnx heximal, but i think i got my solution to my problem. Thanks for your time. Until next time.. Thanks again budy

Answer (score 0):

you may suppress exception raising in vb in the following way:

```
on error resume next 
doSomeDangerousStuff
if err.Number <> 0 then
'here is some optional error handling code
 MsgBox "Exception occured: " & Err.Description
end if
on error goto 0
```

Comment: Thanks heximal, i used on error resume next and it solves the prompt of error message. But it affects my output. The error message that i'am talking about is subscript out of range.

Comment: I hava a program that monitor a folder name it prog1 and a program that will render the file in database name it prog2. Everytime that a new file is being drag and drop to the monitored folder, prog1 will get the filename and pass it to prog2 to render it to the database. There is no problem regarding drag/drop no matter how many files you drag/drop to a monitored folder. My problem is there is a pop up error when i try to copy and paste 5 files and above to a monitored folder saying that subscript out of range.

Comment: Is theres a difference between drag/drop vs copy/paste regarding the time when its actually being copied to a monitored folder? Thanks for anyone who can help me

Comment: do i understand right that you now see this error somewhere? e.g. in the console or in some message box?

Comment: no, there is no difference between drag and drop and copy/paste approach. may be it would be better if you show your script entirely?

Comment: why is it that when i drag/drop or cut/paste 10 files into monitored folder everything goes fine. But when i copy/paste 10 files there is a 2 prompt "subscript out of range".

Comment: i use wshshell.run to run the prog2 wherein i also pass the 3 parameters.

Comment: i will have no new idea anymore, until i see your script code

Comment: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'passing the values to program2 strCommand = """" & App.Path & "\Prog2.exe """ & strArgs(0) & ";" & Trim$(.cFileName) & ";" & strArgs(1) WshShell.Run strCommand

Answer (score 0):

after the declaration of your function/sub  put

on error goto error_filter

'your code is here'

before the ending of your sub/function put this

error_filter:

if err.description = (the error description you want to eliminate) then

exit sub

end if